# How can I convert my DateTimeOffset to a Twitter Date/Time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, twitter, datetimeoffset

How can I convert a `DateTimeOffset.Now` into a twitter-compatible date/time?

Twitter example:

```
<created_at>Tue Apr 07 22:52:51 +0000 2009</created_at>
```

cheers :)

Comment: [ooook.....](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2941923/revisions). Removing greetings isn't exactly [uncommon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), but in the future I'll add you to the extremely short "don't edit this person's posts, they're a little unbalanced" list

Comment: :) *wink* Cheers mate :) most appreciated ... and being unbalanced keeps me on my toes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *nearly* does it:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;        
string x = now.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

... but it ends up with a colon in the time zone bit. I'm looking at removing that now.

EDIT: Blech. The best I can do at the moment is this:

```
    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;        
    string x = now.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        + (now.ToString(" zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              .Replace(":", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

That's incredibly ugly. Mind you, this is a really ugly date and time format. Does Twitter really not have a more sensible format you can use?

Comment: Cheers Jon. I'm also assuming that DateTimeOffset.TryParse( .. ) will work to read that in?

Comment: @Pure.Chrome: Having added the nastiness to remove the colon, I don't know the best way of parsing... you may want to manually add it in again! As I say, it's probably worth checking if there's a more sensible format you can use.

Comment: @Jon i got the twitter info from their DEV api like here: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Yeah... I just wonder whether there's any way of getting them to give you the data in a saner format. That's a really, really odd format to use.

Comment: @Jon Agreed :) i was hoping to use that linux net time format in ticks or secs or something ...

Comment: @Pure.Krome: There are plenty of human-readable date/time formats with standard representations. We don't need to go down to ticks - but putting the year *after* the time zone offset?

Comment: For parsing into DateTime, ParseExact() worked well for me: http://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2009/05/twitter-date-parsing-in-c/

Comment: @ShawnFeatherly: Right, but this is about formatting, not parsing.